# How to use a variable's value to change the same variable's value?

Tags: c#, variables

So in pseudo code I was taught something like this was possible

```
  x <- 0
  y <- 0
 Repeat 
   Input, y
     x <- x + y
 Until x <- 20
```

But in C# it isn't working. My exact code is

```
while (choice == "yes") {

int TotalCost;

TicketChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if ( TicketChoice == 1 )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Number of Adults:");

        Adults = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        TotalCost = TotalCost + (20 * Adults);

        

    }
}
```

And all of this is in a while loop. Is my syntax wrong or is this not possible in C#? It says use of unassigned local variable but I did declare it. I am new to coding so forgive me if I am asking an obvious question. I have yet to write code for all the other Ticket choices. Adults and TicketChoice are variables I declared before.

Comment: Post the exact full code and we'll tell you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, "it isn't working" doesn't tell us anything about what's going wrong - please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Your C# code is missing the equivalent of `x <- 0`, hence  the complaint about an unassigned local variable. When you wrote `TotalCost = TotalCost + ...`, there wasn't a value in `TotalCost` to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After assigning the value of 0 to ToatalCost it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use while loop

```
    var TotalCost = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Number of Adults:");

        var Adults = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        TotalCost = TotalCost + (20 * Adults);

    } while (TotalCost < 1000);
```

Comment: My while loop is working fine but it wasn't adding 20*Adults to TotalCost. It seems my problem was that I needed to assign a value to TotalCost as well, like you have.